# Ant Rename files maintaining directory structure

Tags: ant

I want to rename files using Ant maintaining their directory structure.

e.g. Assume following directory structure:

```
- copy
    - new
        - testthis.a
```

Using code below, I could rename files containing "this" word to "that.a" using copy task, but they all are getting pasted into "paste" directory loosing their directory structure.

```
<copy todir="paste" overwrite="true">
    <fileset dir="copy"/>
    <regexpmapper from="^(.*)this(.*)\.a$$" to="that.a"/>
</copy>
```

Output:

```
- paste
    - that.a
```

If I change regexmapper to (notice \1 before that.a):

```
    <regexpmapper from="^(.*)this(.*)\.a$$" to="\1that.a"/>
```

It's generating correct directory structure but always prepends word before "this" to "that.a"

Output:

```
- paste
    - new
        - testthat.a
```

Is there any way to rename files maintaining their directory structure without pre-pending or appending any word?

Is there any other mapper which can be used for the same?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<copy todir="paste" verbose="true">
    <fileset dir="copy" includes="**/*this*.a"/>
    <regexpmapper from="((?:[^/]+/)*)[^/]+$$" to="\1that.a" handledirsep="true"/>
</copy>
```

First, setting `handledirsep="true"` allows us use forward slashes to match backslashes. This makes the regular expression a bit cleaner.

Next, I'll explain the gnarly regex by breaking it into parts.

I explode `((?:[^/]+/)*)` into...

```
(
    (?:
        [^/]+
        /
    )
    *
)
```

What the parts mean:

```
(  -- capture group 1 starts
    (?:  -- non-capturing group starts
        [^/]+  -- greedily match as many non-directory separators as possible
        /  -- match a single directory-separator character
    )  -- non-capturing group ends
    * -- repeat the non-capturing group zero-or-more times
)  -- capture group 1 ends
```

The above parts repeatedly match as many subdirectories as possible. The `(` and `)` put all of the matches into capture group 1. Later, capture group 1 can be used in the `to` attribute of `<regexpmapper>` with a `\1` backreference.

If there are no `/` directory separators in a path, then the above parts won't match anything and capture group 1 will be an empty string.

Moving to the end of the regex, the `$$` anchors the regex to the end of each path selected by the `<fileset>`.

In the double dollar-sign expression, `$$`, the first `$` escapes the second `$`. This is necessary because Ant would treat a single `$` as the start of a property reference.

The `[^/]+` matches just the filename because it matches all characters at the end of the path that aren't directory separators (`/`).

### Example

Given the following directory structure...

```
- copy (dir)
    - new (dir)
        - notthis.b
        - testthis.a
    - anythis.a
```

...Ant outputs...

```
[copy] Copying 2 files to C:\ant\paste
[copy] Copying C:\ant\copy\anythis.a to C:\ant\paste\that.a
[copy] Copying C:\ant\copy\new\testthis.a to C:\ant\paste\new\that.a
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This regexpmapper would copy all files irrepsective of their names and extensions. I want to copy only that files which have "this" word and ".a" extension in their names. Any help on this?

Comment: @HelloWorld I've updated my answer to use the `includes` attribute of `<fileset>` to only select `*this*` files ending with `.a`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. One thing I've noticed is, if i put "anythis.a" in "copy" directory itself, it doesn't get pasted in the "paste" directory, for sub-directories it works.

Comment: @HelloWorld I've updated my answer to use a considerably more complicated regex to match files in the root directory. It will match `.a` files within "copy" itself.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `regexpmapper`:

```
<regexpmapper from="^(.*)/([^/]*)this(.*)\.a$$" to="\1/that\3"/>
```

This cuts the path (`\1`) and filename prefix (`\2`), so you can preserve the directory structure.

Also, you can preserve the file extension if you use `\3`in the replacement string.

Comment: I tried the regexpmapper mentioned by you. It copied directory structure correctly but didn't copy and rename actual files containing "this" word and having ".a" extension. All folders were empty.